# Working with iTunes COM interface dates in Python

Tags: python, windows, itunes

Switching from Javascript to Python for scripting iTunes via the COM interface on Windows and am having some confusion with iTunes dates.

Trying to check songs to see which have been added since the last time the script ran and can't seem to figure out how to do that comparison. Googling around for a couple hours hasn't enabled me to make any progress. Javascript had some tricky iTunes date conversion issues so maybe it's similar weirdness, or perhaps I'm just making a noob Python mistake (sorry about that!).

When I print the DateAdded return's type with the type function I get "time" but I can't seem to use any time functions to accomplish my aim. For the song I'm working with for testing, the DateAdded variable prints out as "02/24/18 20:52:02" which is indeed the song's correct date added value. Not sure what additional information might be useful to you if it is an odd iTunes conversion issue, but am more than happy to provide any you request.

Thanks very much.

Comment: maybe this helps https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Comment: Your question is a little vague, with respect to what are you actually asking? Can you give some concrete code example of where the behaviour is unexpected?

Comment: A couple hours of trying things left me so confused I wasn't certain what code might help someone more knowledgeable. Was hoping someone more familiar with datetime would suggest how this sort of comparison should work and either it would do the trick (and reveal me as an idiot...) or shed light on any iTunes weirdness that's going on. With Javascript to convert back to iTunes dates I had to do some real low level bit twiddling and if it's that sort of thing again, I'd be lost in Python.

Comment: Let me boil this down, sans backstory and minus any of my assumptions:

I want to compare a time (as returned by the COM interface) to a date which we will say is originally stored as a string.

This seems like it should be really easy, but for whatever reason I couldn't get any of the examples I found to do the trick and figured I better ask for help. Thanks again and sorry for the vague initial question.

Comment: I did get something working. Under the assumption that the COM interface is returning some sort of custom object, I just took a stab at what some likely fields would be and discovered it did have day, month, and year fields. This enabled me to convert it to a standard Python date. Probably better ways to have gone about it, but it gets the job done.